# How to update my ref onClick on custome component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, state, next.js

What I try to do is to use the state from my child component which is a button. The state of my  child component change when it is clicked. So I get the state of it in the parent from the ref and now I try to use the Ref.

(the end goal will be to do something link `state of child ? <html/> : <html2/>`

*As you can see I tried some solutions but none of them worked so far :/

> Parent component

```
    export default class Chat extends Component { 
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.BtnRef = React.createRef();
          }

        componentDidMount() {
            const RefBtn = this.BtnRef.current.state;
            this.setState({RefBtn: RefBtn})
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            console.log(this.state.RefBtn)
            this.setState({RefBtn: RefBtn})
        }

        handleEvent = () => {
            this.setState({RefBtn: RefBtn})
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div className={"a"} >
                    <div className={""} >
                        ok
                    </div>
                    <ChatButton ref={this.BtnRef} onPress={this.handleEvent} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

> Child component

```
export default class ChatButton extends Component {
    state = {
        active: false,
    }

    getInitialState() {
        return { "showHideSidenav": "hidden" };
    }

    render() {
        const { onPress } = this.props;

        let a = (
            <svg className="bi bi-envelope" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M14 3H2a1 1 0 00-1 1v8a1 1 0 001 1h12a1 1 0 001-1V4a1 1 0 00-1-1zM2 2a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V4a2 2 0 00-2-2H2z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M.071 4.243a.5.5 0 01.686-.172L8 8.417l7.243-4.346a.5.5 0 01.514.858L8 9.583.243 4.93a.5.5 0 01-.172-.686z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                <path d="M6.752 8.932l.432-.252-.504-.864-.432.252.504.864zm-6 3.5l6-3.5-.504-.864-6 3.5.504.864zm8.496-3.5l-.432-.252.504-.864.432.252-.504.864zm6 3.5l-6-3.5.504-.864 6 3.5-.504.864z" />
            </svg>
        )
        let b = (
            <svg className="bi bi-envelope-open" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M.243 6.929l.514-.858L8 10.417l7.243-4.346.514.858L8 11.583.243 6.93z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M7.184 10.68L.752 14.432l-.504-.864L6.68 9.816l.504.864zm1.632 0l6.432 3.752.504-.864L9.32 9.816l-.504.864z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M8.47 1.318a1 1 0 00-.94 0l-6 3.2A1 1 0 001 5.4V14a1 1 0 001 1h12a1 1 0 001-1V5.4a1 1 0 00-.53-.882l-6-3.2zM7.06.435a2 2 0 011.882 0l6 3.2A2 2 0 0116 5.4V14a2 2 0 01-2 2H2a2 2 0 01-2-2V5.4a2 2 0 011.059-1.765l6-3.2z" clipRule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        )
        return (
            <button 
                className={this.state.active ? "btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl false" : "btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl true"} 
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
                    onPress();
                }} >
                {this.state.active ? b : a}
            </button>
        );

    }

    toggleChat() {
        var css = (this.state.showHideSidenav === "hidden") ? "show" : "hidden";
        this.setState({ "showHideSidenav": css });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the state to the parent and pass it as prop to the child, then let the child render itself based on the prop?

Comment: You seem to be [missusing Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) concept. What you need instead is [something different](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

Comment: Example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-worker-w3fwb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you don't need to use refs, you can just fire an event from the child component like you have already done.
Parent component will have its state, something like this:

```
state = {
  visible: false
}
```

Also you need to add a handler for the event:

```
handleToggle = () => {
  this.setState(visible => ({ visible: !visible }));
}

<ChatButton onPress={this.handleToggle} />
```

And finally pass the state to the child:

```
<ChatButton onPress={this.handleToggle} active={this.state.visible} />
```

So that, in the child you can switch your JSX

One hint: don't use refs, in most cases you don't need it, try to find ways how to do something without them. Refs is often really hard to debug